# 'nosetests' not recognized on Windows after being installed and added to PATH

Tags: python, installation, nose, nosetests

I'm on [exercise 46 of Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html), and I'm meant to install nose and run nosetests. I've installed nose already using pip, but when I run nosetests in the directory above the 'tests' folder, I get the error:

```
'nosetests' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

If it's relevant, I've already modified the PATH variable to include full path of `Python27/Scripts` and `Python/Lib/site-package`.

Comment: I haven't used command line on Windows for a long time, but it looks like the command nosetests is not in one of the directories (folders) specified in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: In Windows, I've had to either start a new command prompt, or even log out and log in again, for a change in PATH made via the "System Properties" window to take effect.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser That did it! Thank you so much, I can't believe it was such a trivial issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still having trouble after following Warren Weckesser's instructions try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Using pip: `pip uninstall nose`

I found this worked for me on Windows 8 64 bit

Answer (score 3):

I use Windows and I had the same problem.The LPTHW book is based on Linux OS and it's a bit difficult for windows users.
When I typed nosetests, I got errors. Then I typed python -m nose , as per said by Spellstaker and it worked perfectly. I have noticed that in most cases we need to add 'python -m' at the beginning to make it work on Windows. [image: See here]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `python -m nose` in PowerShell.

This worked for me in Windows 7, 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Command: `python -m nose` or `py -m nose`

Remember you should stay in the current virtual environment to run the nose if it is installed locally. Check the local environment name **lpthw** in the PowerShell after you activate the same.