# Shell Script to Batch file for Jenkins

Tags: shell, batch-file, jenkins

I am trying to create a Jenkins build on a windows box, and am running into a situation where I am completely unsure of what to do. 
I have the following shell script which I need to convert to a windows batch script for when the build runs. I have I believe gotten the set correct for the variables, just not sure what to do with the rest of it:

```
#set POWERUSER=DTCURTISS
#set POWERPASS=password
set POWERUSER=auto
set POWERPASS=password
set TAG=$BUILD_NUMBER
set PATH=.env/bin:$PATH
set SAUCEUSER=DarthOpto
set ACCESSKEY=accesskey
set IGNOREPAGEHEADERLOCATION=True
set MAINMENUCLICKTILES=False
set LOGDIR=logs

source ../.env/bin/activate

cd trunk/automation/selenium/src
#pip install -r pip-requires.txt

rm -rf logs

nosetests --nocapture --with-xunitmp -a valallmod --processes=$THREADS --process-  timeout=5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to get far if you don't know [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file). Besides, simply "translating" `bash` to `batch` is not going to magically make it work on Windows.

Variables are referenced as `%VARNAME%`, not `$VARNAME`. Fix that first.

Windows uses `\` as path separator, not `/`. Change all your paths to use `\`

When you want to append to `PATH` variable in Windows, you've got to make sure you don't destroy the existing `PATH`. You do this through `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\whatever\yourpath\`

Something similar to `source` would be batch's `call` followed by another batch file name. However you can't just pass it `../.env/bin/activate` as that is not a batch file. You would need to convert that file to batch as well. And don't forget to convert the path separator to `\`. This is also where my second point comes into play. The file you pasted is rather *simple*. I've got no idea what's inside that other file or whether it can be "translated".

The `#` is not a valid comment in batch, you need to use `REM` or better yet `::`

`rm` and it's flags is not a Windows command. An equivalent would be `rmdir /s /q`

Finally, `nosetests` is neither bash nor batch. It's an external program. You've got to make sure it is available in Windows. As a pre-emptive step before your next question, read this: ['nosetests' not recognized on Windows after being installed and added to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328678/nosetests-not-recognized-on-windows-after-being-installed-and-added-to-path)